# How to add a column in postgresql based on other columns

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have a column called "newname" populate with a string with varying names based on a sql query in postgresql.

```
IF fullstate='California' and county in (71 65) THEN newname='TEMECULA'; 
IF fullstate='California' and county in (27 51) THEN newname='SHIPROCK'; 
IF fullstate='California' and county in (29 107 19 31 53 79 83 111 37 39 69) THEN newname='TULE'; 
IF fullstate='California' and county in (25) THEN newname='PHOENIX'; 
IF fullstate='California' and county in (59) THEN newname='LOS ANGELES';
IF fullstate='California' and county in (73) THEN newname='ORANGE'; 
IF fullstate='California' and county in (41 13 1 81 87 85 75) THEN newname='YERBA BUENA';
```

The "newname"column is being created based on two other columns "fullstate" and "county". I'm new to postgresql and can't figure out if I need a function or a CASE WHEN statement to get this query to work.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression should do the trick for you:

```
CASE    
WHEN fullstate = 'California' AND county IN (71, 65) THEN 'TEMECULA'
WHEN fullstate = 'California' AND county IN (27, 51) THEN 'SHIPROCK'
WHEN fullstate = 'California' AND county IN (29, 107, 19, 31, 53, 79, 83, 111, 37, 39, 69) THEN 'TULE'
WHEN fullstate = 'California' AND county IN (25) THEN 'PHOENIX'
WHEN fullstate = 'California' AND county IN (59) THEN 'LOS ANGELES'
WHEN fullstate = 'California' AND county IN (73) THEN 'ORANGE'
WHEN fullstate = 'California' AND county IN (41, 13, 1, 81, 87, 85, 75) THEN 'YERBA BUENA'
END AS newname
```

Comment: Do I need to add some kind of statement pointing to the table? When I use the above code it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @sbell423 this is just the case expression, not a full statement. You could use it in either a `select` or `update` statement.